# error C2039: 'advance' : is not a member of 'boost::token_iterator<TokenizerFunc,Iterator,Type>'

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using MVSE 2012 C++ and Boost. However I get an error:
[image: this is not a chicken. trust me.]
Here's the code for reference. I'm just trying to get input such as 5:00 PM, convert it into integer 5, integer 00 and string PM. (later I want to manipulate that information).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > 
    tokenizer;
    boost::char_separator<char> sep(": ");
    int value1 [2];
    tokenizer tokens1(str1, sep);
        for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter1 = tokens1.begin();
        tok_iter1 != tokens1.end()-1 ; ++tok_iter1)
            for (int iii=0; iii <= 1; iii++)
                value1[iii] = atoi(str1.c_str());   
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like boost::tokenizer::iterator doesn't support operator- in this code part:

```
tokens1.end()-1
```

Use boost::prior(tokens1.end()) or std::advance(tokens1.end(), -1) instead